# Alternate option for call a function in all controller in spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a notification section in my user area in my project. For the users there is lot of pages actually and each page i need to show the notification on top but each page calling different controller function. So my question is there any option for me to get this notification list on each user pages without calling the same notification fetching function on all controller or on all request mapping function.

Comment: you can try implementing ajax call at page. This ajax call will call one controller.

Comment: Yes i am familiar with ajax call but is there any option in spring itself to load this like by writing on interceptor or any library option we have in codeigniter?